# Egit fetch & pull connection refused

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, egit

I've installed Egit plugin for eclipse on two ubuntu systems and created two new project on two sytems and shared(team>share) it. What's the proper way to do fetch & pull projects with other users with Egit?

Error `connection refused`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure a new remote configuration, with both fetch and push URI filled.
You need to choose one of the [available protocols](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html):

[image: Egit new remote configuration dialog]

- **local**: file:// (do you have a direct shared path between your two servers?): that is the easiest way to share between projects, no listeners of any kind needed.
- **git**: that means port 9418 isn't blocked by your local firewall. And a git daemon needs to be active to listen for requests.
- **ssh**: means that git is installed in a standard way, because ssh daemon often don't authorize custom environment variable to be set when opening/accessing a remote shell session.
- **http(s)**: you need a http listener, at least gitweb within an Apache httpd for instance.

If you have just created a repo on one server, you need to clone in the other server (no Egit required), and then "Add an existing Git repo into this view" (the Git Repository view): that way, a first (fetch,pull) remote addresses will already being set!

---

To summarize the comments below:

- using the git protocol means: nothing to do on the client side (with Egit) except using a git:// url.
  But you need to have a git daemon running on the server side, otherwise nothing will listen your request (done by default on port 9418).
- you can use that protocol over ssh or not (ssh is  not mandatory, but without it, there is no authentication with the git protocol alone)
- if you use ssh, again you need the openssh daemon running on the server side, and an ssh-based layer like gitolite (still on the server side) is better, because it won't just execute any commands in a remote secure shell, but will allow only git command, and only on the rights repos/branches/directories.

Comment: Actually I want to use git protocol but it's giving connection refused error. I tried ssh, and somehow it worked to clone but when I change at one side and doing push it's not updating on the other side.

Comment: The exact thing what I need is, all the developers should share a project push & pull their changes to one another and how do I perfectly do this?

Comment: @user465464: git protocol means you have launched the git daemon on the server side. Did you? ssh itself won't allow push. It has to be ssh over git, or ssh over a script calling the right git commands (like gitolite). Again, if you have a way to directly access the files through a shared path ,the local protocol is the easiest to setup.

Comment: Yes, as you said I have installed `git-core` and `gitosis` on desktops and trying to push and pull the changes so that I can setup it up for the developers if it works. Then how do I use the `git` protocol as it is listed there. could you give some procedure editing your main answer, please!

Comment: Can't I share the project with only `git` protocol without `ssh` or `sharing` the directory. I'm failing to understand that how to push the changes to another comptuer and on destination how to see the changes made with egit.

Comment: As you said, when I try to clone a repo with only `git` protocol why it's showing connection refused error?

Comment: @user465465: as mentioned in http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way, you need to have launched the `git daemon` for any `git://` clone to work. (`sudo -u git git-daemon --base-path=/home/git/repositories/ --export-all`). If you use gitosis (or even better gitolite), any clone will be over ssh. You can clone with git protocol without ssh if you don't have gitosis at all (and if the `git daemon` has been launched)

Comment: without using command, can't do every thing graphically with Egit

Comment: @user465465: the commands I mention (mainly `git daemon`) are on the server side (the one with the remote target repo). EGit is on the client side (and shouldn't involve any commands)

Comment: Ok I understood about `git daemon` that it's only for server side. Knowing this feeling that I've understood something about git beacuse of you. you helped me a lot and I'll call you master of CVCS & DVCS repos. Hey it's not a flatter, because I saw you many places when every the question is asked about vcs and you'll give your 100% solution

Comment: Finally I cloned a repo from a remote desktop system with ssh protocol via `Egit` graphically. Where I'm failing is when every I update the porject(creating file/directories or editing files) after `team>remote>fetch from` or `team>remote>push`, it was saying upto date but I couln't see the changes on the other computer. Actually I don't know the proper way how to push and pull updates.

Comment: @user465465: note that a fetch won't update your files unless it is a fast-forward update. I.e. if you have made any commit on your side, the fetch won't touch your files at all: it will only get back the history of the remote branch in your '`remotes`' namespace within your local Git repo. To merge/get those files within your current branch, you need to pull those files (`pull = fetch + merge`): `Team > pull`. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories and http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch

Comment: Oh..ok. When I pull, I getting the error message. I"ll post that error prompt once I'm back to work place. Thanks a lot!. Until then I'll go through the links.

Comment: It's successfully pushing and pulling changes without any error but the file/directories I created on one system, could not see on another. When every I use push & pull on either side, it's saying up-to-date but How do I see the newly crated files on another system after the push/pull

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and comments!. I'll open a new question that regarding push and pull. Thank a lot!

Comment: @user465464: ok, I have updated this answer with the conclusions made in those comments so far.